# Beanstalk fails to abort deploy on npm start failure

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We have some apps running on Beanstalk and several environments, so I'm pretty experienced with configuring it and running those apps in Beanstalk and NodeJS.

But there is one issue I could never understand or find a solution for:
If, for some reason, npm start (or whatever is configured to be the start command) fails and the exit code is different than 0, instead of aborting the deploy and setting it as a failed one, it just keeps trying, in an eternal loop. With time this consumes all the CPU and there were situations where Beanstalk completely lost control of everything and an enviroment rebuild was the only option.

So, I did manage to work around it, using the Immutable deploy method. With this option, the deploy WILL fail, because the instances Health will never be green and the whole thing will rollback. But I'm not really happy with this because 1) it doesn't address the issue, only covers it and 2) immutable deploys take forever to complete/rollback.

Any ideas?